# Chat angular websocket, display element sequencially

Tags: angular, websocket

I'm working on a chat with Angular and socket.io.
Server can emit many events in a few time, front has to treat every event one after the other.

```
// My socket service
message: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
this.socket.on('messageToServer', (data) => {
  this.message.next(data);
});

// My component
this.socketService.message.subscribe(
  async (msg) => await this.display(msg)
);

async display(msg): Promise<void> {
  try {
    console.log('start speaking');
    await this.botSpeak(msg.message);
    this.displayedMessages.push(msg);
    console.log('stop speaking');
  } catch (e) {

  }
}
```

here is the log :

```
start speaking
start speaking
stop speaking
stop speaking
```

it's normal because the socket was emitted twice, but i need to wait treatment one before treatment 2 to get this correct log :

```
start speaking
stop speaking
start speaking
stop speaking
```

Option 1 : use an array with a boolean displayed or not.
Option 2 : use a queue ? how ?
I'm a bit lost about the best way to do that, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap) is the solution here, here's the sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mdk9s7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

double click on the button and look at the console, output will emit in order.

replace that fromEvent with the observable returned by your service and it'll work as expected.

and well if you're feeling too lazy to open the link lol, here's the code:

```
this.socketService.message.pipe(
    concatMap(msg => from(this.display(msg))) // use from operator to convert a promise to an observable
).subscribe({
    next: _ => {}
});
```