# Flutter web socket, async method between events

Tags: flutter

I have a websocket and the server can send many events (messages) in a few time.
for each event i have to call an async function which speak the sentence (flutter-tts) before display the second event.
What would be the correct way to do that ?
use an array stream ?
use a List.builder ?

I need to exactly reproduce this post (in angular/rxjs) in Flutter :

[Chat angular websocket, display element sequencially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68690841/chat-angular-websocket-display-element-sequencially)

Thanks for your help !

Added some code for better understanding :

```
...

    socket.on('messageToClient', (data) {
      print("socket $data");
      MessageModel message = MessageModel.fromJson(data);
      setState(() {
        _messages.add(message);
      });
    });

ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: _messages.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int indexMessage) {
                      print("index");
// Seems it's not waiting here
                      return FutureBuilder(
                          future: _speak(_messages[indexMessage].message),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                              default:
                                if (snapshot.hasError)
                                  return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                                else {
                                  return TextMessage(
                                    message: _messages[indexMessage].message,
                                    author: _messages[indexMessage].author,
                                    hint: _messages[indexMessage].hint,
                                    options: _messages[indexMessage].options,
                                    giveVoice:
                                        _messages[indexMessage].giveVoice,
                                  );
                                }
                            }
                          });
                    }),
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this i what i did :

```
BehaviorSubject<MessageModel> _streamMessage =
      new BehaviorSubject<MessageModel>();

// then on my socket event
socket.on('messageToClient', (data) {
  MessageModel message = MessageModel.fromJson(data);
  _streamMessage.sink.add(message);
});

// and then on the setState
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _init();
    _streamMessage.asyncMap((event) async {
      await _speak(event.message);
      setState(() {
        _messages.add(event);
      });
    }).toList();
  }


// and finally the widget
                ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: _messages.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int indexMessage) {
                      return TextMessage(
                        message: _messages[indexMessage].message,
                        author: _messages[indexMessage].author,
                        hint: _messages[indexMessage].hint,
                        options: _messages[indexMessage].options,
                        giveVoice: _messages[indexMessage].giveVoice,
                      );
                    }),
```

Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by:

> for each event i have to call an async function _which speaks the sentance before display the second event

If what you mean is to *display* the "sentance" using Flutter, you could try this:

Ideally you would be able to `listen` to the websocket. Doing this would give you a `Stream` of sorts (I think). Then use a `StreamBuilder` widget in Flutter to update the UI on every event from the websocket. Maybe create a `ListView.builder` within the `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: Hi Emil, if i understand well, i have to create a stream of type MessageModel, add in it on every event received for the socket, make my async treatment (mean a future i guess for the async function speak), pushing my message in the messages array, and then call a listview.builder ?

Comment: First of all: What do you mean by speak?

Comment: i mean speak ;) there is a plugin called flutter-tts who speak a given sentence. For more information it's a chat between a human and a bot. The bot can send 2 in a few time : 1. Hello, 2. how are you. In Flutter i need to achieve this : speak Hello, then display, then speak how are you, then display